# Oracle limiting number of query result

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi below query gives result more than 2 records. I can't get the exact first record without using `rownum` concept in oracle. Please help me to get the exact first row from the Query in ORACLE without using subqueries?

```
SELECT OLD_VALUE 
FROM table_name 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME='name'
AND ID=1000 
ORDER BY OLD_VALUE DESC
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?  In Oracle 12C you can add "fetch first 1 rows only" after the order by

Comment: am using Oracle sql developer version 4.0.1.14

Comment: Yes but what version of the database?

Comment: maybe you need to think about your filtering criterias. But its kind of hard to give you some hints without knowing more about your table structure, contained data aso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by this question.

If you are only looking for the first row, and you don't want to use rownum or max, you can do this as an alternative:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  FIRST_VALUE(OLD_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OLD_VALUE)
FROM
  TABLE_NAME
WHERE
  COLUMN_NAME='name'
  AND ID=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(OLD_VALUE)
FROM table_name 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME='name'
AND ID=1000
```

Comment: old value is in String format...so it is giving wrong value based on the string length

Comment: There are no such thing as 'exact first record of query result' in Oracle. You need to order it Yourself first. In Your example ORDER BY and MAX does the same. Maybe You can work around using e.g. MAX(TO_NUMBER(OLD_VALUE)).

Comment: @anandbaskar: if `order by old_value` in your original query is working properly, then `max(old_value)` will also work "properly", i.e. it will return the same "maximum" as the `order by` would